# Figuring out how to specify paths based on Netbeans project structure

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, netbeans

I have code that looks like this:

```
 String path;
 public DisplayDataServlet()
 {
   path=getServletContext().getRealPath("/leaflet/temp");
 }
```

[This throws a huge NullPointerException,this might be because I am having trouble specifying a valid relative path using the Netbeans folder structure.](http://pastebin.com/Jd0Qjwu6)The file location is `Web Pages/leaflet/temp` in the Netbeans IDE.

Tried with `getServletConfig().getServletContext()`,still getting the same error.
I have tried the following paths:

```
1. /leaflet/temp
2. /Web Pages/leaflet/temp
3. /webcontent/leaflet/temp
4. /WebContent/leaflet/temp
5. /build/web/leaflet/temp
```

I keep getting the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
ServletContext servletContext = request.getSession().getServletContext();
```

instead of using `getServletContext()` directly.

Comment: I am trying to call it from the `constructor` where `request` is not available,is that a bad way of calling `getServletContext`

Comment: Not bad way, but isn't it throwing a NPE ?

Comment: That might be because the `path` does not exist `getRealPath()` will throw a NPE

Comment: Try it once with the `request` object, move your code where `request` is available